# FabricJS image in vue component not appearing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs

I want to use manipulate images on a canvas with FabricJS inside a VueJS app. In my view component, I am passing in a prop called `background` and using `fabric.Image.fromURL()` to load it onto the canvas, but nothing is appearing:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Edit Game</h1>
    <canvas id="game-board" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>

    <img :src="background" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { fabric } from 'fabric'

export default {
  mounted() {
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('game-board');

    fabric.Image.fromURL(this.background, function(oImg) {
      canvas.add(oImg);
    });
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'background'
    ])
  }
}
</script>
```

In the attached image, you'll see `background` is being loaded properly into an img tag but not into the canvas.

[canvas and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfn6P.png).

[This Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-nightingale-wtclu?file=/src/App.vue) works, but doing nearly the exact same thing locally does not.

Comment: did you tried to put   canvas.renderAll(); after   canvas.add(oImg);? Also did you receive any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Add image only on load

```
  const image = new window.Image()
  image.src = this.image_link
  image.onload = () => {
    let imgInstance = new fabric.Image(image, {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
    })
    imgInstance.scaleToWidth(this.canvas.getWidth())
    this.lockElementMovement(imgInstance)
    this.canvas.add(imgInstance)
  }
```